# Why do variables set by $_GET() not retain values

Tags: php, get

The idea is that one script calls another with parameters, then the called script re-calls it's calling script with the same parameters.

Calling Script

```
<?php
    //search_members - Test.php
    $id = '9999';
    $search_1 = '';
    $search_2 = 'Bloggs';
    $sort = '3';
    echo '<a class="results" href="editmember - TEST.php?id=' . $id . '&search_1=' . $search_1 . '&search_2=' . $search_2 . '&sort=' . $sort .'">View</a>';
?>
```

Called Script

```
//edit_member - TEST.php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['exit']))
  {
    $id = $_POST['id']; 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; 
    //Passed Parameters
    //$search_1 = $_POST['search_1'];    
    //$search_2 = $_POST['search_2'];
    //$sort = $_POST['sort'];

    echo 'Display Parameters 2</p>';
        echo 'search_1' . $search_1 . '</p>';   //NOTDEFINED error???
    echo 'search_2' . $search_2 . '</p>';   //NOTDEFINED error???
    echo 'sort' . $sort . '</p>';           //NOTDEFINED error???
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<a class="results" style="bold;color:black" href="search_members - Test.php?search_1=' . $search_1 . '&search_2=' . $search_2 . '&sort=' . $sort. '">Continue Search</div>';   //V2 
    exit();
  }
else 
  {
  $id = '9999';
  $first_name = 'Fred';
  // Set passed parameter variables
  $search_1 = $_GET['search_1'];
  $search_2 = $_GET['search_2'];
  $sort = $_GET['sort'];
  
    echo 'Display Parameters 1</p>';
    echo 'search_1' . $search_1 . '</p>';   
    echo 'search_2' . $search_2 . '</p>';
    echo 'sort' . $sort . '</p>';
    echo '</p>';
    
?>  
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <table>
  <tr><td><label for="id">ID:</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="id" name="id" maxlength="6" size="6" value="<?php if (!empty($id)) echo $id; ?>"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td><label for="first_name">First Name:</label></td> 
      <td><input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" maxlength="30" size="30" value="<?php if (!empty($first_name)) echo $first_name; ?>"></input></td>
  </tr>
  <!--Passed Parameters Stored
  <input type="hidden" id="search_1" name="search_1" value="<?php echo $search_1; ?>"></label> 
  <input type="hidden" id="search_2" name="search_2" value="<?php echo $search_2; ?>"></label>    
  <input type="hidden" id="sort" name="sort" value="<?php echo $sort; ?>"></label> 
  -->
  </table>
  <p class="text_centered">
    <input type="submit" value="Exit" name="exit" />
    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update" />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="delete" />
  </p>
  </form>
 </div>
<?php
  } 
?>
```

The question is why the script in the format displayed above produce 'Undefined' errors for the variables holding the parameters. It's like the variables set by $_GET are cleared after the POST.
Can someone explain why this is?

If you uncomment the sections shown below, the script works fine.

```
  //Passed Parameters
  //$search_1 = $_POST['search_1'];    
  //$search_2 = $_POST['search_2'];
  //$sort = $_POST['sort'];

  <!--Passed Parameters Stored
  <input type="hidden" id="search_1" name="search_1" value="<?php echo $search_1; ?>"></label> 
  <input type="hidden" id="search_2" name="search_2" value="<?php echo $search_2; ?>"></label>    
  <input type="hidden" id="sort" name="sort" value="<?php echo $sort; ?>"></label> 
  -->
```

This is probably down to an utter failure to comprehend how a php script works...but i'm just learning.

Thanks in advance for any response :)

Comment: It's because those variables come from what is submitted in each http request to the server running the php script. They only contain what was in that particular request. Subsequent requests are likely to have different variables attached, or possibly none. And http is a stateless protocol

Comment: Relevant: [PHP - $_POST and $_SESSION](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37505765/2943403) and [data between pages: $_SESSION vs. $_GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2510456/2943403) and [$_GET or $_SESSION for passing variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38110704/2943403)

Comment: Thanks....  though i still need to do some work to understand what you actualy mean. My problem really is visualizing how php scripts actualy execute. It seems like the first 'request' passes variables and results in the setting of variables using $_GET(), followed by input via the method="post" form.  This then triggers another 'request' which this time has no variables submitted with it.

Comment: Yes each time you execute the php script its because a new http request has been sent by the browser. The webserver receives the request and, if it's a .php file, sends it to the php executable to run and return a response. Each time the php script runs its like it's the first time it ran, and it remembers nothing from last time (unless you specifically use things like Session or databases or files to store and retrieve information.)

Comment: N.B The post request caused by submitting your form likely does have data in it, but it would be in the body of the request and retrievable via $_POST during that request.

Answer (score 0):

$_GET, $_POST and all other variables are reset for every request. The PHP file is run for the request and when the HTML is sent to the browser the program exits, and the variables are cleared.

To store any information between requests you need to put them in the `$_SESSION` array.

```
$_SESSION['search_1'] = $_GET['search_1'];
$_SESSION['search_2'] = $_GET['search_2'];
$_SESSION['sort'] = $_GET['sort'];
```

you can access them

```
echo '<p>search_1' . $_SESSION['search_1'] . '</p>';   //NOTDEFINED fixed
echo '<p>search_2' . $_SESSION['search_2'] . '</p>';   //NOTDEFINED fixed
echo '<p>sort' . $_SESSION['sort'] . '</p>';           //NOTDEFINED fixed
```

Comment: The $_GET() variables seem to be cleared, the $_POST() ones remain set though.....